# Find node by name by using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

Trying to find nodes by name. Here is my xml:

```
<Project>
 <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="..\..\CommonAssemblyInfo.cs">
      <Link>Properties\CommonAssemblyInfo.cs</Link>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Global.asax.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Global.asax</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\myproject1.csproj">
      <Name>Myproject1</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Myproject2.csproj">
      <Name>MyProject2</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\myproject3.csproj">
      <Name>MyProject3</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
 </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Here is my code to get all Name nodes from above XML:

```
  f = File.open(projectpath)
  @doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)
  #print f.read
  names = @doc.xpath("Name")
  print names

  f.close
```

My code got nothing from the XML search.

Comment: Some people downvote questions that don't actually ask a question. Or maybe it was a reaction to your nonsensical first sentence, which doesn't seem to relate to the question. In any case, I could tell what you meant. I've upvoted it which more than compensates. :)

Comment: @MarkThomas: It is not your job to counteract other people's right to vote! Upvote, sure, but only if you think that this is a "great" question.

Comment: Downvote because "got nothing from the search" is not the output of research and/or debugging.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Touché!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the wildcard path construct (`//`), otherwise you are just looking at the elements at the root level.

```
names = @doc.xpath("//Name")
```

Perhaps you were thinking of CSS searching, which would use exactly the string you supplied:

```
names = @doc.css("Name")
```

Or maybe you have used the `search` method which tries to make an educated guess whether you are using CSS or XPath. It would work properly in this case:

```
names = @doc.search("Name")
```

Comment: Thanks, this one 'names = @doc.search("Name") ' works, but not sure why names = @doc.xpath("//Name") not working on my case.

Answer (score 0):

```
names = @doc.xpath("//itemgroup//name")
```